# Why does IE11 open MP4 files in Windows Media Player instead of rendering within the browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, video, video-streaming, mp4

I'm opening a direct link to an MP4 file that within Firefox and Chrome both render inside the browser's native player. When I load it in IE11, it forces the video top open within Windows Media Player. The problem is when loading it as part of the page's background, both Chrome and FireFox correctly render it within the page (using a jQuery plugin), but in IE11 it again opens up a Windows Media Player window.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are opening the video file directly rather than embedding it on your site.

As per Degru's answer on [This Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/36hd8b/ie_11_opens_up_media_player_to_play_videos/creuumv), you probably need to use the HTML5 `<video>...</video>` tag like so:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) is the W3Schools documentation

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) is a working example